# Export content of multiple files to a CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Im trying to export the content of multiple *.log* files into a single CSV.

I think I'm close, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm guessing it's somewhere in the foreach:

```
$dir = "\\server\c$\folder1\folder2"
$filter = "*.log"

$files = Get-ChildItem -path $dir -filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 10

foreach ($file in $files){
Get-Content $file | convertTo-csv | export-csv -path "\\server\share\test.csv"
}
```

I've tried to write the `get-content` line in so many ways, but none seem to work.

When I do **$files.name**, it lists up the files perfectly.

The error I get from the code is "`Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Myname\filename1.log' because it does not exist.`. I don't understand why, because I never spesified the `c:\users` path..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `Import-CSV` cmdlet to load the CSV instead of the `Get-Content` and `convertTo-csv` cmdlet:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -path $dir -filter $filter | 
    Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 10 | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

Import-Csv -Path $files | Export-Csv "\\server\share\test.csv"
```

Comment: Oh, that I did not know. Worked flawlessly! Thanks. I got an warning called "WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers." - Any ideas?

Comment: You can specify them using `Import-Csv -Path $files -Header @('FirstHeader', 'SecondHeader', ...)`

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
get-content -path $file.Fullname
```

Comment: Ah, thats it! Thanks! However - my csv seem to contain the wrong information. It doesn't contain the information that is within the .log files. It contained a coloum called 'length' and below it a bunch of numbers. Any ideas? The .log files contains some regular text like date and information.